# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'branche'

Tags: html-select, viewdata

I'm trying to do dropdownlist it is working bring data from DB but with below error, anybody can help me to solve this issue please.

There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'branche'.

.Net MVC 5

my controller

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        //sysEntities1 db = new sysEntities1();
        //ViewBag.branches = new SelectList(db.branche, "brancheID", "brancheName");



        sysEntities1 db1 = new sysEntities1();

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> branches = db.branche.Select(
            b => new SelectListItem { Value = b.brancheName, Text = b.brancheName });
        ViewData["brancheName"] = branches;


        return View();
    }
```

My View

@Html.DropDownList("branche", (IEnumerable)ViewBag.branches, "Select Branch" , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

Answer (score 0):

Try with below mention code.

```
@Html.DropDownList("branche", (SelectList)ViewData["brancheName"], "Select Branch", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Or

```
@Html.DropDownList("branche", (SelectList)ViewBag.branches, "Select Branch" , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindness help but the error still as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check below mention code which I have used.

```
public IEnumerable<DropDownDTO> GetCity()
    {
        IEnumerable<DropDownDTO> objDropDown;

        using (var context = new AKJIEntities())
        {
            objDropDown = (from x in context.CityMasters
                           where x.IsDeleted == false && x.Status == true
                           orderby x.City
                           select new DropDownDTO
                           {
                               Value = x.CityID,
                               Text = x.City
                           }).AsParallel().ToList();

            return objDropDown;
        }
    }

ViewBag.CityList = new SelectList(GetCity(), "Value", "Text");

@Html.DropDownList("CityId", (SelectList)ViewBag.CityList, "Select City", new { @class = "dropdown_list" })
```

Hope this help you.